# How to log exception stacktrace for Spring's SimpleMappingExceptionResolver

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-mvc

I'm working on a project where the exception handling was created by someone else who is no longer here to help.

They've created the following bean which catches all uncaught exceptions and forwards to a JSP View.

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
  <property name="exceptionMappings">
    <map>
      <entry key="java.lang.Exception" value="error"/>
    </map>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultErrorView" value="error" />
</bean>
```

It works fine, but what if I want to get a hold of the exception thrown and report it in our logs?  How do I forward this to a Java class instead of a View?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the properties for [`warnLogCategory`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/handler/AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.html#setWarnLogCategory%28java.lang.String%29). See the [class Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/handler/SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.html).

Comment: Thanks, but what are the values available for loggerName?

Comment: Interesting... it works although it's displaying it as a "warning" and not an "error" in the logs.  It works though, thanks.

Comment: Well that is what the docs say - it will log exceptions at the WARN level. If you want to change how it's logged I'd look into subclassing `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` and override the ` logException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request)` method - should be simple